# Change the mail id on aws after verification and use that mail id to send mails using SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, amazon-web-services, smtp

I want to change mail id through which i want to send mails using smtp and application hosting is on aws.

**My production.rb looks like:**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: Host IP}
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      :user_name => username,
      :password => password,
      :authentication => :login,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

**devise_mailer.rb looks like:**

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  address = Rails.env == 'production'? 'support@domain' : '*****@domain'  
  default from: address, reply_to: address
end
```

**aws verified email**

```
Email Feedback Forwarding:enabled   
DKIM Settings Generated:yes
Bounce Notifications SNS Topic:none 
DKIM Verification Status:failure
Complaint Notifications SNS Topic:none  
DKIM Signing:verification attempts failed
Delivery Notifications SNS Topic:none   
MAIL FROM Domain:amazonses.com
```

And i am getting error although my email id is verified.
**Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.
):** Please help me and tell me if i am wrong somewhere.